# Check if regenerate_session_id() function actually works / Other security questions

Tags: php, security, session

I am building a website and i would like to secure it against **Session Hijacking**. Reading for this i came across someone saying that:

A general rule of thumb is to generate the session ID each time a user changes his access level.

> 1.When a user log in
>   2.When a user log out
>   3.When a user get administrative access

For what is worth, my website will be seperating the access levels into **users logged-in** and **users logged-out**. All forms are submitted using the POST method.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Setting the variable initialy to false
$_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] = FALSE;

//to use SSL

$serverport = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

$server_http_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$server_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (headers_sent()) 
{
    die("HTTP headers have already been sent ");
}
else
{
if($serverport != '443')
{
ob_start();
exit(header('Location: https://'.$server_http_host.$server_request_uri));
}

}

if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))

{
if(isset($_POST['TOKEN']) && $_POST['TOKEN'] == $_SESSION['TOKEN'])
{
//Open database connection
require_once('connect_db.php');

//Calling functions.php that includes all custom functions
//ErrorHandler()
require_once('functions.php');        

$email = $_POST['EMAIL'];
$password = $_POST['PASSWORD'];



$statement = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE email=:email AND pwd=:password ");
$statement->bindParam(':email',$email);
$statement->bindParam(':password',$password);
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
try{

$result = $statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->rowCount(); // shows how many times the user is available in the user_details table
$data = $statement->fetch(); //fetches the data related to that user from user_details table


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
//this is custom function   
echo ErrorHandler($e);
}


if($rows == 1)
{
//this means that the user has inserted the correct credentials 
//regenerate session_id each time there is a change in the level of privilege to mitigate SESSION FIXATION  
session_regenerate_id(true);

//turning logged in variable to true as soon as it finds a match
$_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] = TRUE;

//saves the email into a session so it can be used in mainpage.php
$_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $email;

//redirect to main page
header('Location:https://www.example.com/mainpage.php');

}
else
{
echo "<br />Wrong username or password!<br />";
}
}//closing *if(isset($_POST['TOKEN']) && $_POST['TOKEN'] == $_SESSION['TOKEN'])*
}//closing *if($_POST['SUBMIT'])*

//creating a random token to inject in our HTML form
$token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));

//store the random token in the session variable so we can later compare it to the one in the HTML form
$_SESSION['TOKEN'] = $token;
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p>Email: <input type="email" name="EMAIL" /> </p>
<p><input type="hidden" name="TOKEN" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" /></p>
<p>Password <input type="password" name="PASSWORD" /> </p>
<p><input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

The script accepts input email and password from the user,checks the database and if it finds a match it redirects the user to the mainpage.php.

**mainpage.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
//the code to set the header must be called before output begins
session_start();


$serverport = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

$server_http_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$server_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (headers_sent())
{
die("HTTP headers have already been sent ");
}    
else
{
if($serverport != '443')
{
ob_start();
exit(header('Location: https://'.$server_http_host.$server_request_uri));
}
}



if(($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN'] == TRUE) && isset($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']))
{
$email = $_SESSION['EMAIL'];
echo $email;

//Calling functions.php that includes all custom functions
//LogOut()
require_once('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['LOGOUT']))
{
//its a custom function that is used for logging out    
LogOut();
}


echo '
<form method="POST" action="mainpage.php">
<p><input type="submit" name="LOGOUT" value="Log Out" /></p>
</form>

';

}
else
{
echo "Please login in order to use example.com";
}


?>
```

Is there a way for me to check if the way i have built these 2 scripts really regenerate the Session ID? I am using Firefox's extension LIVE HTTP headers but i am not sure if i am reading it correctly.

Also, i cannot find a way to track down and read the content of COOKIES stored while using my browser (either Chrome or Firefox or even IE11). How can i do that?

Another question that is related with security:
Implementing an anti-CSRF token:
Do i need to implement an anti-CSRF token for each form in my website [i guess the answer is Yes but i want to confirm it]? Should each token be different than the token used in a previous form? For example the token in index.php to be different than the token used in mainpage.php if it had a form as well.

Does the token technique prevent against any other kind of attack?

I would be glad if you indicate wrong programming in the code above, so i can correct it and learn at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: Live HTTP Headers was fine several years ago but now we have better tools like Firebug (together with Firecookie) or, simply, the built-in tools (both in Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to focus on your questions and not necessarily a thorough `code review`, since I think your questions are the main reason you're posting.

A simple way to check your current session id or `PHPSESSID` is to check under Chrome's `Developer Tools > Resources > Cookies`. You'll see the (initially-generated) session ID. You can check this value *before and after* a user logs in. If the `value` changes, your session id has actually been regenerated.

You can also view cookies in Firefox by right-clicking the current page, going to `View Page Info` and using the `Cookies` tab.

On CSRF (prevention) tokens, the answer varies. People use different methods to go about them. I would say a majority of websites set a token in `$_SESSION` upon any `regenerate` of the session id. So for the duration of the current session, the CSRF token will remain the same and check against hidden inputs for *that* CSRF token.
On the other hand, I've also heard of regenerating a CSRF token for *every single form* that is client-facing. Your way of doing it is up to you. Nothing is 100% bulletproof, but getting as close to 100% as you can is the idea.

Take a few minutes to read up on CSRF tokens and the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Best of luck!